# Gstreamer Change State Function

Tags: gstreamer

I am new to Gstreamer. I have a question about change_state function for plugin.
As I read in this guide: http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/pwg/html/chapter-statemanage-states.html#section-statemanage-filters

```
static GstStateChangeReturn
gst_my_filter_change_state (GstElement *element, GstStateChange transition)
{
  GstStateChangeReturn ret = GST_STATE_CHANGE_SUCCESS;
  GstMyFilter *filter = GST_MY_FILTER (element);

  switch (transition) {
    **//Downwards state change;**

  ret = GST_ELEMENT_CLASS (parent_class)->change_state (element, transition);
  if (ret == GST_STATE_CHANGE_FAILURE)
    return ret;

     **//upward state change**
  }

  return ret;
}
```

I really don't know how we can use **parent_class** and call **parent_class->change_state**
Because in init function of this element:

```
gst_my_filter_class_init (GstMyFilterClass *klass)
{
  GstElementClass *element_class = GST_ELEMENT_CLASS (klass);

  element_class->change_state = gst_my_filter_change_state;**strong text**
}
```

**element_class->change_state** was assigned to **gst_my_filter_change_state**. Why can we still call  **element_class->change_state** in **gst_my_filter_change_state** when element_class->change_state  is assign to another function.
Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Change `gst_my_filter_class_init (GstMyFilterClass *klass)` to something like this:

```
gst_my_filter_class_init (GstMyFilterClass *klass)
{
  GstElementClass *element_class = GST_ELEMENT_CLASS (klass);
  parent_class = (GstXyzClass *) g_type_class_peek_parent (klass);
  element_class->change_state = gst_my_filter_change_state;**strong text**
}
```

And add a `static` global variable `GstXyzClass *parent_class;` somewhere near the top of your plugin. Just `GstXyzClass` will be the type of the Element you are inheriting from, e.g. `GstElementClass`. Just look at other plugin sources for examples.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer. Actually,this code I quoted from that guide can run normally.But the thing I can not understand is in header file we declare: `GstMyFilterClass {GstElementClass parent_class;}`  It means GstElementClass is the father class of GstMyFilterClass 
but why can we use **parent_class** in source file of this plugin(.c file)? Sorry for my lacking of knowledge in Gobject , but as I know **GstMyFilterClass** is  a struct and(not class like C++) and the attribute **parent_class** can not be used in function of plugin(in C++ we can easily use attribute in method of class). And in the  **gst_my_filter_class_init** :

```
gst_my_filter_class_init (GstMyFilterClass *klass)
{
  GstElementClass *element_class = GST_ELEMENT_CLASS (klass);

  element_class->change_state = gst_my_filter_change_state;//assign to function pointer  state change
}
```

Does The statement:**GstElementClass *element_class = GST_ELEMENT_CLASS (klass);** mean we cast GST_ELEMENT_CLASS (klass) to get its parent class(**GstElementClass parent_class**)?
If it is true,so the **change_state** function pointer of **parent_class** is not Null. So In

```
gst_my_filter_change_state (GstElement *element, GstStateChange transition)
{
  GstStateChangeReturn ret = GST_STATE_CHANGE_SUCCESS;
  GstMyFilter *filter = GST_MY_FILTER (element);

  switch (transition) {
    **//Downwards state change;**

  ret = GST_ELEMENT_CLASS (parent_class)->change_state (element, transition);
  if (ret == GST_STATE_CHANGE_FAILURE)
    return ret;

     **//upward state change**
  }

  return ret;
}
```

what is  **GST_ELEMENT_CLASS (parent_class)->change_state (element, transition)**? 
As I know every GstElementClass has a default function **change_state** but in this situation  function **change_state** has assigned to another pointer function(**gst_my_filter_class_init** do this assignment) Is it right? Hope to receive your answer soon. Thank you very much